Consume Server-Sent Events in a Next.js route handler
I have a Supabase Edge Function (written in Deno) that stream a message every second.
/// <reference types="https://esm.sh/@supabase/functions-js/src/edge-runtime.d.ts" />

const msg = new TextEncoder().encode("data: hello\r\n\r\n");

Deno.serve((_req) => {
  let timerId: number | undefined;
  const body = new ReadableStream({
    start(controller) {
      timerId = setInterval(() => {
        console.log(msg);
        controller.enqueue(msg);
      }, 1000);
    },
    cancel() {
      if (typeof timerId === "number") {
        clearInterval(timerId);
      }
    },
  });
  return new Response(body, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
      "Content-Encoding": "none",
    },
  });
});

And I wrote this Next.js route handler to consume the stream, but it does not stream at all : the fetch just hung forever.
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'

export async function GET() {
  const params = {
  };

  console.log("Before Fetch");
  const res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:54321/functions/v1/stream", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization":
        "Bearer <JWT>",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(params),
  });

  if (res.body) {
    const rstream = res.body;
    const reader = rstream.getReader();

    let done = false, value = undefined, chunks = [];
    do {
      ({ done, value } = await reader.read());
      if (done) {
        break;
      } else if (value) {
        chunks.push(value);
      }
    } while (!done);
    return Response.json({ data: chunks });
  }
  return Response;
}

How to correctly consume a SSE stream in a Next.js route handler ?

It should work with Deno 1.44. Run deno upgrade
There was a bug in 1.43 where the stream was not properly flushed with automatic response body compression. Fix PR: https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/23991
